# How to know if a submit button clicked on a form with get method when exists another form in the template?

Tags: python, django

In my base template  I want to have a search text box with a submit button on the top of every template. My button name is 'searchbutton'
I put it in a form with get method 
I want to use this for all views in my application

I have a view with 2 more forms , one of theese has pagination with page buttons
I tried:

```
 if ('searchbutton') in request.GET:
```

but this is true even user change pages on pagination.

How can I know when user clicked the search button to filter rows as I want?

Thanks in advance

Kostas

Comment: How is the pagination implemented on the front end? (EDIT: you should really use separate view for searches, though)

Comment: I use cool_paginate for pagination. It works well. I thought if i could know in get when user clicks the search button , I could modify the result query before pagination

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining all your forms as `django.forms.Form` and not just as pure HTML, you should be able to handle it in your view.

E.g.

```
class FooView(generic.FormView):
    def post(self, request):
        search_form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        other_form = OtherForm(request.POST)
        if search_form.is_valid() and search_form.has_changed():
            # Handle Search Form here.
        elif other_form.is_valid() and other_form.has_changed():
            # Handle Other Form here.
```

HOWEVER! If this is a Search Function I suggest that instead of handling the logic on every view, you instead make the form submit to a specific view/url each time.

E.g. you create a form that submit to `/search?q=` where `q` is your query. And then you only create a single `SearchView` that handles this logic.

Comment: My forms are forms.ModelForm defined. Have I use post method? What if with get method?